# Docker: How to ADD a service via ENV variables?

Tags: installation, docker-compose, environment-variables, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I have built a Docker Cron Environment to run Cronjobs based on `alseambusher/crontab-ui` using `alpine:3.15.3` & it works great.

For it to work I have had to install a number of things via the Dockerfile, editing it & adding python so it could run a python script, perl for another service, openssl so I could use a Self-signed certificate, etc.

As it stands the Container is a lot bigger, which is fine, but if I am to share the container others won't necessarily want or need the services I have added & will likely need other that I haven't.

---

I would like to be able to add a command in the ENV of a Docker Compose to add services at startup without having to do a full build each time. I'm sure it would be ***simpler*** to add `build:`>`args:` & have it rebuild the container each startup, but my goal is to have it add to an image ***only*** the services that each user needs & declares in the Docker-Compose ***with no need to have the files for the build on the system***.

1. I know this will mean a longer startup depending on the services, I'm okay with that.
2. I know it's normal to run cron on the host & have it call into containers, but cron on Windows WSL has to be manually started every time the WSL starts & is easy to forget about & can't really be automated aside from on startup, & I'd like to do this entirely inside Docker.

---

How can I add an ENV like `SERVICE_INSTALL` to have it run in BASH (which is already added in the Dockerfile & present at /bin/bash) at container startup?
Ideally I'd like to be able to add multiple `SERVICE_INSTALL` lines if at all possible.

- Example:
- - `SERVICE_INSTALL1='apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python'`
- - `SERVICE_INSTALL2='python3 -m ensurepip'`
- - `SERVICE_INSTALL3='apk add --no-cache perl perl-html-parser perl-http-cookies perl-lwp-useragent-determined perl-json perl-json-xs'`
- Or, if nothing else:
- - `SERVICE_INSTALL=apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python && perl perl-html-parser perl-http-cookies perl-lwp-useragent-determined perl-json perl-json-xs && && wget && curl && nodejs && npm`
- - but then that leaves the problem of installing things through pip or npm.

---

---

I have tried adding a `command:` to the Docker-Compose but every variation I have tried does not work. I'm also concerned with this method as from my understanding a `command:` ***replaces*** the startup script in the container, not adds to it, so that is not ideal, regardless, it doesn't seem like an install `command:` is possible anyway

I have tried: (Each as a single `command:` not together)

```
    command: 
      - BASH apk --update add openssl
      - /bin/bash apk --update add openssl
      - BASH RUN apk --update add openssl
      - /bin/bash RUN apk --update add openssl 
      - sh apk --update add openssl 
      - /bin/sh apk --update add openssl
      - apk --update add openssl
```

Each ends with a message along the lines of `Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash run apk --update add openssl": stat /bin/bash run apk --update add openssl: no such file or directory: unknown`

**UPDATE:** I discovered a few things trying to get this to work

1. for `command:` to work there needs to ***not*** be any `-` before it
2. anything, even on multiple lines, is considered a single command essentially as though they were all on the same line & have to be separated with an &&
3. it will repeat the command or show the error of it failing to execute the command & not continue to next until it is completed.

- - for example the command `mkdir -p /test` leaves no logs, but the container never actually starts. While portainer says it's running trying to bash into it gives a `is restarting, wait until the container is running` message
- - `mkdir "-p /test"` repeats this message

```
mkdir: unrecognized option:  
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2022-02-02 18:21:20 UTC) multi-call binary.
Usage: mkdir [-m MODE] [-p] DIRECTORY...
Create DIRECTORY
    -m MODE Mode
    -p  No error if exists; make parent directories as needed
```

- 3 times 3-4 seconds apart, them 7 seconds, then 8 seconds, then 15 seconds, 27 seconds, 53 seconds, then hits a minute & continues to grow a few seconds each try.
  It also returns the same `wait for the container to be running` message when trying to bash in
- - `mkdir -p "/test"` seems to be the correct formatting, it appears to work but leaves no logs & when attempting to bash in it connects, shows the terminal, then exits, attempting to reconnect shows the same `container is restarting` message, likely because the container stopped once the command was finished & is set to `restart: always`. commenting out the restart command the container exits.
- - `mkdir -p "/test"` followed by a new line with `supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` (the default start command) has mkdir reporting `mkdir: unrecognized option: c`
- - adding `"supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf"` leaves no logs & a restarting container.
- - reversing the order, with `supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` 1st has supervisord reporting the error `Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['mkdir', '-p', '/test'] For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h`
- - `bash -c "supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` with a new line & `&& mkdir -p /test` with a new line & `&& mkdir -p /test2"` runs with a working container, but no directories created
- - reversing the order seems to work & creates the directories, with a running container

```
    command:
      bash -c "mkdir -p /test
      && mkdir -p /test2
      && supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf"
```

- - Which indicates that it will run them in order, but only proceeds to the next after the one finishes.
- - a test confirmed that the same can be done with other dependencies so long as the initial startup is last. I'd rather have the container start 1st, then install the dependencies while it is running as they are not required for the container itself to run, but rather are added for use in the cronjobs that will be running on a schedule, so if the container starts & the dependencies cannot be used for the 1st 2, 3, even 5 or 10 minutes that might only affect their 1st attempt if it happens to be in that time.

This is alright, I now understand better how the `command:` option works, but it still requires users to know & properly include the default start command. The `command:` options are also a lot more particular & easy to get wrong, while ENV variables are something every docker user knows, has experience with, & is simpler to implement

Comment: alpine linux doesnt have bash installed it.

Comment: Also you might want to write an entrypoint script and then utilise commands to be passed to it or let it just dynamically discover or iterate over service env vars

Comment: I have added BASH already in the Dockerfile, so it IS installed. & I figured an Entrypoint script would be needed, but HOW can I "let it dynamically discover" them?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle if you have a solution that utilizes an Entrypoint.sh that would dynamically discover service ENV variables that sounds like exactly what I'm asking for, please explain or leave it as an answer